# How to sftp a zip file in Bluemix, store it and read it using zip api of Java?

Tags: java, file-upload, zip, sftp, ibm-cloud

We have a zip file which needs to be SFTP to the application for processing. This file is read using zipped input stream and then processed. These files will be stored for a certain duration and purged after the same? Also is there any size limitations on files being uploaded. 
Size of these files can be varying from 1 GB - 1 MB basis certain criteria. 
The storage has be performed for say 90 Days. (Consider the Avg to be somewhat 400 MB - 500 MB). In Bluemix what is the suggested way around for such scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Object Storage](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorageV2/index.html) service to upload the mentioned files. It is based on OpenStack. There are not that many restrictions and you could access the files via the documented API. Note that there are two versions of the Object Storage and the differences are explained at the beginning of the linked document. Depending on your setup it could be that Object Storage V1 more suitable to your application.